# performing a merge function in python, when I don't want the values to repeat

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

HI This is a follow up from one of my previous questions [how do I perform a vlookup equivalent operation on my dataframe with some additional conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61513874/how-do-i-perform-a-vlookup-equivalent-operation-on-my-dataframe-with-some-additi/61513942#61513942)

As in the other question, my first dataframe is

```
list = ['Computer', 'AA', 'Monitor', 'BB', 'Printer1', 'BB', 'Desk', 'AA', 'Printer2', 'DD', 'Desk', 'BB']
list2 = [1500, 232, 300, 2323, 150, 2323, 250, 2323, 23, 34, 45, 56]
df = pd.DataFrame(list,columns=['product'])
df['number'] = list2
```

and what if my 2nd dataframe has multiple values for say 'AA' as shown below

```
list_n = ['AA','AA','BB','BB','CC','DD']
list_n2 = ['Y','N','N','Y','N','Y']

df2 = pd.DataFrame(list_n,columns=['product'])
df2['to_add'] = list_n2
```

and this is how it would look

```
  product to_add
0      AA      Y
1      AA      N
2      BB      N
3      BB      Y
4      CC      N
5      DD      Y
```

when I perform `pd.merge(df, df2, on="product", how="left")`
I get this

```
 product  number to_add
0   Computer    1500    NaN
1         AA     232      Y
2         AA     232      N
3    Monitor     300    NaN
4         BB    2323      N
5         BB    2323      Y
6    Printer1     150    NaN
7         BB    2323      N
8         BB    2323      Y
9       Desk     250    NaN
10        AA    2323      Y
11        AA    2323      N
12   Printer2      23    NaN
13        DD      34      Y
14      Desk      45    NaN
15        BB      56      N
16        BB      56      Y
```

As you can see now there are multiple rows for AA and BB. I just want the first value (or one of the values) for 'AA' (and 'BB') to be pull across (without altering the sequence of the dataframe of course). In short don't want multiple rows. just to clarify, my df2 has over 6000 rows and I don't know which entries are duplicated.

so the answer should look something line

```
     product  number to_add
0   Computer    1500    NaN
1         AA     232      Y
2    Monitor     300    NaN
3         BB    2323      N
4    Printer1     150    NaN
5         BB    2323      N
6       Desk     250    NaN
7         AA    2323      Y
8    Printer2      23    NaN
9         DD      34      Y
10      Desk      45    NaN
11        BB      56      N
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df_m = pd.merge(df, df2, on="product", how="left")

m = df_m["product"].isin(df2["product"]) & df_m["product"].eq(df_m["product"].shift())
df_m = df_m[~m].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_m)
```

This prints:

```
     product  number to_add
0   Computer    1500    NaN
1         AA     232      Y
2    Monitor     300    NaN
3         BB    2323      N
4   Printer1     150    NaN
5         BB    2323      N
6       Desk     250    NaN
7         AA    2323      Y
8   Printer2      23    NaN
9         DD      34      N
10      Desk      45    NaN
11        BB      56      N
```

Comment: thanks mate, that was helpful, only issues is my df2 is rather large and I dont know how many entries are duplicated. I have made it more clear in my question now. So in short its not just AA that's duplicate there might be 50-60 other entires (that I dont know of) might be duplicated in df2.

Comment: @user13412850 I see you have edited the question. Do you want to keep the duplicated values corresponding to "Printers", "Computers"...?

Comment: yeh those values are fine if duplicated, only the values I am pulling from df2 shouldn't be duplicated.

Comment: no not quite, I have edited my question again and at the bottom added a table of how it should ideally look like

Comment: perfect! that worked for me! thanks again for your efforts!